# Sentence based search

Tags: php, search

Search for `WORD` in `CATEGORY`

How would I go about extracting the `CATEGORY` and `WORD` from the search query? (above is an example search query) The user will enter

The search query will look like the one above the example. I need to find what is the word before FOR and what is the word before IN so I can use it in a search against the database.

Comment: You mean you want to extract the words from a string that are inside brackets?

Comment: Is category guaranteed to be on the right? (no)

Comment: are you asking for sql or php help?

Comment: It's best if you show code of what you have tried so far.  Even if it does not work showing you've put some effort into the problem helps here.  You'll get better answers and your question will be less likely to be closed.

Comment: The search query will look like the one above the example. I need to find what is the word before FOR and what is the word before IN so I can use it in a search against the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly because your question is vague but if you have

```
$string = 'Search for WORD in CATEGORY';
```

and you need to extract `WORD` and `CATEGORY` from that string to use later on in a database query you could do something very simplistic like

```
$string = 'Search for WORD in CATEGORY';
$words  = explode(' ', $string);  //Break that string into an 
                                  //array of items based on the space
$w      = $words[2];  //The third item in the array
$c      = $words[4];  //The fifth item in the array
//echo $w gives you WORD, 
//echo $c gives you CATEGORY
//these can be used in your query (and you know how to do that properly, right?)
```

**BUT** that assumes that WORD and CATEGORY will ***ALWAYS*** be in the same position in `$string` and that they will not have a space in them.  That's a rather large assumption.  Example...

```
$string = 'Search for WORD in A CATEGORY';
```

would break this.

I'd use this as a starting point (and cautiously)